# How to correctly import BillingResponse with newest version of billing client (billing:2.0.1)

Tags: java, android, gradle, in-app-billing

I'm upgrading my version of android billing api from 1.2.2 to 2.0.1.
But now my import of the '''BillingResponse''' api is returning an error.  How can I properly import BillingResponse with version 2.0.1?

I'm working with gradle inside of Android Studio.

I've tried:
- Cleaning and rebuilding my project
- Closing the application and reopening
- Restarting my machine
- File > Sync project with gradle files

None of those worked so far with 2.0.1, but when I go back to 1.2.2 version of the android billing API it works again!  I could not find any documentation that BillingResponse had been deprecated so I was expecting it to work even with an updated api

---

My relevant gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation project(':libcocos2dx')
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:17.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
  implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.1'
```

---

My import statements inside of BillingProvider.java which implements PurchasesUpdatedListener:

```
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient;
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient.BillingResponse;
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient.FeatureType;
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient.SkuType;
```

^ note that all of the other imports are working here except the .BillingResponse one!

I expected the BillingResponse to still be available in 2.0.1 but it can't seem to find it now that I have upgraded...

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: it was "Cannot resolve symbol BillingResult"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_releases_notes

> BillingResult return values
>
> APIs that previously returned a BillingResponse integer value now
>   return a BillingResult object. BillingResult contains the
>   BillingResponse integer as well as a debug string that you can use to
>   diagnose errors. The debug string uses an en-US locale and is not
>   meant to be shown to end users.

Comment: Awesome thanks.  I also found I can check against codes just using BillingResponseCode instead of BilliingResponse
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.BillingResponseCode

Answer (score 0):

instead of importing `import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient.BillingResponse;`
I used `BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK` object instead and it worked